# Show that $(C^1([a,b]), d_{\infty})$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $C^1([a,b])$ the space of the function that are continuously differentiable on the interval $[a,b]$. For $f,g\in C^1([a,b])$, let
$$
d_{\infty}(f,g):=\lVert f-g\rVert_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert.
$$

> > Show that $C^1([a,b]),d_{\infty})$ is **not** complete.

My idea is to use 
$$
C^1([a,b])\subset C([a,b]), 
$$
i.e. to find a sequence $(f_n)$ in $C^1([a,b])$ that converges to some $f\in C([a,b])$ with respect to the supremums norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$ but which is **not** continously differentiable.

Then, $(f_n)$ should be a Cauchy sequence in $C^1([a,b])$ that does not converge in $C^1([a,b])$ (otherwise $f$ would be continously differentiable).

Now, I do have to find such a sequence... and did not have an idea yet.

**EDIT**

Maybe on $[-1,1]$ consider
$$
f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}},~~f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}.
$$

$f(x)$ is not differentiable in $x=0$, hence not continuously differentiable on $[-1,1]$. The functions $f_n$ are continously differentiable on $[-1,1]$ and uniformly converge to $f$.

Comment: That example works on $[a,b]$ after appropriate translations! I suggest you to post your - modified- edit as an answer to this question and then accept it!

Comment: What do you mean with appropriate translations?

Comment: The example is OK if $a=-1, b=1$. You should now find a way to generalize it to an arbitrary interval. HINT: An affine change of variables $x=\alpha X+\beta $ transports your example sequence $f_n(x)$ on $[-1,1]$ into a sequence on $[\beta-\alpha , \alpha+\beta]$.

Comment: What I mean is that your $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$. If $0 \in [a,b] $, then this is a great example. Otherwise you will have to modify your $f$ such that this point of non-differentiability is moved into $[a,b]$. The change of variables @GiuseppeNegro suggested should work.

Comment: @Andrew Got it, thanks.

Comment: I think I have to show that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy-sequence. But that should be rather easy: Let $\varepsilon >0, \tilde{\varepsilon}=\varepsilon/2$. Then $\lvert f_n(x)-f_m(x)\rvert=\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)+f(x)-f_m(x)\rvert\leq\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert + \lvert f_m(x)-f(x)\rvert$. Moreover, $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\leq \lvert 1/n\rvert$ and, similarly, $\lvert f_m(x)-f(x)\rvert\leq\lvert 1/m\rvert$. Hence, for $N$ large enough, we have $\lvert f_n(x)-f_m(x)\rvert\leq 2\tilde{\varepsilon}=\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\geq N$.

Comment: $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\leq \lvert 1/n\rvert \le 1/n$ is false

Comment: @zhw.Why is that false? $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert = \lvert \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^2}\rvert\leq\lvert\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{1/n}-\sqrt{x^2}\rvert=\lvert\sqrt{1/n}\rvert\leq\lvert 1/n\rvert=1/n$

Comment: @zhw Dont see why this is false.

Comment: $\sqrt {1/n} > 1/n, n = 2,3,\dots $  But note $\sqrt {1/n}$ will give the result.

Comment: You are right. Then I just write that $\lvert f_n(x)-f_m(x)\rvert\leq \lvert\sqrt{1/n}\rvert + \lvert\sqrt{1/m}\rvert\leq 2\tilde{\varepsilon}<\varepsilon$ for $n,m$ large enough. That should be correct then.